# how to uninstall apache web server from AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried different commands but still unable to uninstall/remove apache server.
here are few command which i have tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I have also tried this command:

```
httpd -k uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt remove --purge apache2
```

Should uninstall apache. Next you could do an autoremove to remove not used packages.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already tried the below command, i suggest you to check if there is any configuration file exist related to apache

sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

try using the below command

** whereis apache2**

Incase if you find any directory belongs to apache ..remove it manually